# GRUB 1.99 CentOS 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, centos, grub

I just added CentOS 7 to an existing Ubuntu system (using GRUB 1.99).  When I do a `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it detects the CentOS, and adds two entries (one looks like normal, one like rescue).  However, when I try booting them, I get `error: you must load the kernel first`.

How can I configure grub to boot CentOS? I'd prefer autoconfigure, but, if need be, I'll type in the commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 ships with GRUB 2.02.  Chances are, 1.99 doesn't have the right stuff to load the CentOS 7 kernels, so you will need to upgrade to 2.02.

You're almost there (running `grub-mkconfig`) but unfortunately you will need to boot from a CentOS 7 rescue disk (USB or DVD) and re-install GRUB 2.02 over top of 1.99 first.  2.02 will recognize and boot Ubuntu but not the other way around.

I strongly suggest you take an image of your hard drive with a tool like CloneZilla before progressing, just in case, and, if you haven't already, read through:

[RHEL 7 System Admin Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader.html)
[Fedora GRUB 2 Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader.html)

Then

- Boot from a CentOS rescue disk.
- Install grub to /dev/sda  (or whichever device is your hard drive - it could be /dev/hda if you have an IDE drive)
- Exit the rescue shell (reboot your machine)

GRUB 2 will start.  Hopefully your CentOS entries will be valid (unless 1.99 created erroneous entries).

If not, you will need to boot into CentOS using a GRUB 2 boot disk like Supergrubdisk.org

Once in CentOS 7, run the `grub mkcnofig` command to correctly set up the CentOS 7 entries (and it will detect the Ubuntu install).